# Use PHP to get the value from a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem working with javascript, so this is my javascript code for displaying `data` . My concern here is, I want to get the value of `data` to use in *php*. For instance, the value is **Mark** . Specially for querying *mysql*.
Thank you.

```
$(".feedback").html('Value: ' + data);
```

Comment: Use AJAX. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: @user3783243 yah. I found the answer in AJAX and echo the value in php. Great friend! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to add the "data" into a hidden input value that belongs in a form.

```
<form action='test/add' method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="add data value here with js"></input>
    </form>
```